# Is there any way to get the tag of `UIButton` while animate `UIScrollView` ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with 50 `UIButtons`. I am trying to animate those by changing offset of `UIScrollview`.

```
NSTimeInterval animationDuration =  scrollView.contentSize.width/80;
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn |UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

But when I click on any of the `UIButton`, I am getting last two tags which is 48 & 49.

If I do not animate `UIScrollView`'s content offset it works fine & perfect. 
Is there any way to get the tag of `UIButton` while animate `UIScrollView` ? 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: when u animate this the animation stops at the end points of the content. Which always will contain the buttons with last tags.

Comment: @JasmeetSingh can you please suggest something ? Any way to do it ?

Comment: yes for sure! but please elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: When you say "when I click on any of the UIButton, I am getting last two tags", do you mean that after the animation (which as Jasmeet points out, will put the last two buttons onscreen), you can subsequently scroll (by hand) to previous buttons, and when you tap them you tags 48 and 49?